# Connections between Lambert ProductLog and Bernoulli numbers

Tags: lambert-w, bernoulli-numbers

The [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) have many (as demonstrated [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61252/why-do-bernoulli-numbers-arise-everywhere)). Here is one property/characteristation:

$$\frac{t}{e^t-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} t^k$$

Conspicuously missing from the MathOverflow thread is any occurrence of Lambert's W function (or ProductLog). However, the wikipedia page has one tantalizing reference (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_13)).

Can anyone elaborate on this connection?

Comment: Do you refer to

 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_13

?